# Using moment.js' fromNow() function in UTC

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, momentjs

I've got a VueJS filter that converts a given date into the fromNow() format.

```
fromNow(date) {
            return moment.utc(date).fromNow();
        }
```

The timestamp that's provided is generated through my Laravel backend and is UTC anyway so I don't see why this is still basing itself off the user's system and throwing results such as "in 5 hours". I need it to be fromNow in UTC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably pass the format as `.format()`.

This works for me

```
Vue.filter('ago', function (value) {
    if (value) return moment(String(value)).utc().format('DD-MM-YYYY').fromNow()
})
```